# Flutter -- :app:flutterBuildDebug FAILED

Tags: android, flutter

I have installed flutter on my computer following all steps in the website to the dot.
When I give the command

$flutter run

I get an error

```
    [ +250 ms] :app:flutterBuildDebug FAILED
[   +5 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'flutterBuildDebug' property 'sourceFiles' during up-to-date check.
[   +1 ms] > Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\Vidya\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InputPersonalization\TextHarvester\WaitList.dat'.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 2s
[        ] 10 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 9 up-to-date
[ +757 ms] "flutter run" took 11,552ms.
Gradle build failed: 1
```

Help !

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Android Studio properly and if yes then I suggest:

1. Create a new app in Android Studio.
2. Let the app completely load up.

possibly Gradle isn't being picked by flutter and that should solve your problem

Comment: Actually I have done that and I am able to develop apps quite well through Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you upgrade all your Android SDKs, and Android Studio.
And add the $paths like so:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Applications/AndroidDev/sdk"

export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/Applications/AndroidDev/sdk/ndk-bundle"

export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

Use your own paths specific to your environment.